# What is wrong with this very simple switch statement?

Tags: javascript

The evaluations in the `console` print in the second line seem correct, but the switch statement won't work. And I am not getting any errors.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    console.log(i % 3 === 0, i % 5 === 0);
    switch (i) {
        case i % 3 === 0:
            console.log(i, " by three");
            break;
        case i % 5 === 0:
            console.log(i, " by five ");
            break;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vL4omdxs/

Comment: You're completely misunderstanding `case` statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comment said, that's not how you use switch/case.
You evaluate the condition in switch, then create different behaviours using cases.

Here is your code slightly modified (actually not so slightly, there's a small math twist):

```js
var res = document.getElementById('r');
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    //console.log(i % 3 === 0, i % 5 === 0);
    switch (i % 15) {
        case 0:
            r.innerHTML += i + " by three and five<br>";
            break;
        case 3:
        case 6:
        case 9:
        case 12:
            r.innerHTML += i + " by three<br>";
            break;
        case 5:
        case 10:
            r.innerHTML += i + " by five<br>";
            break;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="r"></div>
```

---

Just a hint (offtopic, but might help): switch/case is not the best approach for the 3/5 problem. See how much simpler it looks using ifs:

```js
var res = document.getElementById('r');
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        res.innerHTML += "<br>" + i + ": ";
        if (i % 3 == 0) {
            res.innerHTML += "by three ";
        }
        if (i % 5 == 0) {
            res.innerHTML += "by five ";
        }
    }
```

```html
<div id="r"></div>
```

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget that cases are based on the result of switch evaluation.

Comment: that's a nice edit. thanks for the extra help.

Answer (score 1):

Case expressions are tested for strict equality so you need to change the switch from `switch (1)` to `switch (true)`. However note that only one of the case blocks will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the way to do the switch statement. It must be:

```
switch (i % 3) {
    case 0:
        ...
        break;
    case 1:
        ...
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression within `switch` brackets is compared with the expression after `case` keyword. Take your code as example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    console.log(i % 3 === 0, i % 5 === 0);
    switch (i) {
        case i % 3 === 0: // if (i) equals (i % 3 === 0), run this branch
            console.log(i, " by three");
            break;
        case i % 5 === 0: // if (i) equals (i % 5 === 0), run this branch
            console.log(i, " by five ");
            break;
    }
}
```

And please remember, "equal" here means `===`. Since your `case` expressions all return boolean, they'll never be equal to your `i`, which is a number.